# How to read JSON in Spring Boot? - JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `X` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`);

Tags: json, angular, spring-boot, jackson

I am sending data from an Angular application to SpringBoot. The application creates an order and sends it to the server. My problem is that the server does not receive the correct object.

I console.log the output to be sent to the server, and looks alright:

```
    {
        "user": {
            "username": "Yomerito",
            "address": "Aquimerito 1234, Roswell NM 88000",
            "credit": "4444-0000-0000-0001"
        },
        "cart": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "foodName": "Tacos de Barbacoa",
                "price": 20,
                "cuisine": "MEXICAN",
                "description": "Borrego\nasado en horno de piedra ",
                "isEnabled": "Y",
                "imageUrl": "tinyurl\n.com/moleVerdeImage"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "foodName": "Kebab",
                "price": 10,
                "cuisine": "ARAB",
                "description": "rico Kebab",
                "isEnabled": "Y",
                "imageUrl": "tinyurl\n.com/moleVerdeImage"
            }
        ],
        "status": "PENDING"
    }
```

The methods I use in Angular are

1. createOrder() to create the order out of client, cart, and status
2. onSubmit() to send the data.

```
    onSubmit(): void {
        this.purchaseService.postPurchase(this.createOrder()).subscribe({
            next: (data: any) => {


                let retVal = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
                // let retVal = JSON.stringify(data)
                if (retVal === ("OK")) {

                    this.router.navigate(["/purchase"])
                }
            },
            error: err => {
                console.error(err.message)
                alert("onSubmit error: " + err.message);
            }
        });
    }

    createOrder(): IOrden {
        this.searchService.orden = {user: this.checkoutForm.value, cart: this.searchService.cart, status: "PEND"}
    }
```

On SpringBoot, trying to use @RequestBody or @ModelAttribute:

```
package com.slbootcamp.foodbox.controller;

import com.slbootcamp.foodbox.entity.Orden;
import com.slbootcamp.foodbox.entity.User;
import com.slbootcamp.foodbox.jdbc.OrdenDao;
import com.slbootcamp.foodbox.jdbc.UserDao;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@CrossOrigin(origins ="*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
public class OrdenController {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    OrdenDao ordenDao;

    @PostMapping("/cart/placeOrden")
    public int placeOrden(@RequestBody Orden orden) {
//    public int placeOrden(@ModelAttribute Orden orden) {

        logger.info("---------------> Orden: " + orden);
        return ordenDao.placeOrden(orden);
    }

}
```

When I use @RequestBody, the server responds with

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.slbootcamp.foodbox.entity.Cart` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.slbootcamp.foodbox.entity.Cart` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)<EOL> at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 117] (through reference chain: com.slbootcamp.foodbox.entity.Orden["cart"])]
```

and when I use @ModelAttribute, I got:

```
---------------> Orden: Orden(status=null, cart=null, user=null)
```

I searched all over the Internet twice... but couldn't get what the problem is. I am new to Springboot and Angular... which might be the start of the trouble. I would appreciate if you can please shed some light on this...

Answer (score 0):

It look like you are mixing things:

Controller: Your contrller looks fine with @RequestBody this way you expecting
a post request from the Angular.

Your angular request on the other hand look odd it should be something like this:

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

createOrder(): IOrden {        
        return this.http.post("your_url",JSON.stringify(order), httpOptions);        
    }
```

The order is an Angular object defined on its own .ts file.

Before calling the service build the object:

```
const order = new Order(cart, id, status, ...)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried adding the httpOptions and wrapping the order object with JSON.stringify, but still getting the same error: Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.slbootcamp.foodbox.entity.Cart` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`);

Comment: You need to isolate the problem, it's must be mapping issue, try removing the cart from both Angular and Spring and then step by them identify the propery which failed to parsed. Then you will be able to create a new more specific question if you can't resolve it.

Comment: Well, I've been trying to solve this issue since days ago. I know that there is something with the way that CART is built and passed in the order. Looks like Angular does not like an array inside a JSON. If you want to take a look at the full code, the repo is https://github.com/giannifontanot/sl-capstone-foodbox I need to find out why the order cannot contain a cart inside with an array.